# Attach an handler to the click event on a 'a' tag is firing even if I don't click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to listen the click on a 'a' tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", $("#addEvent"), addEvent);
});

addEvent: function () {
   alert("Test");
}

<div style="width: 100%; text-align: right;margin-left: -8px; margin-top:-40px;">
   <a id="addEvent" href="#" >
      <span class="t-icon t-add"></span> Add item
   </a>
</div>
```

When I load the page where this code is located, the alert message is displayed immediatly after the page have been loaded even if I don't click on the 'a' tag.

What can cause this behavior?

I'm using Firefox 14 and jquery 1.7.

Thank you.

Comment: `addEvent:` shouldn't it be `var addEvent =` ?? It just looks misplaced there

Comment: Why not simply
$("#addEvent").on('click',addEvent);

Comment: Yes, `addEvent: function() {...}` is a syntax error. The `addEvent:` part is a label, and then `function() {...}` would give an error "Function statement requires a name" or similar. (Unless you've shown just an extract from some object definition, and your real code uses `someObj.addEvent` within the `.on()` call?)

Comment: Hi guys, I forgot to mention that my function 'addEvent' with the syntax name:function() is because this function is in a namespace. @Musa found the answer and it's because I passed a jquery selector instead of a string to define which element will handle the click event.

Comment: @UnLoCo I don't want to use what you said; "$("#addEvent").on('click',addEvent);" because about what I read about .on(), it's better to specify a parent that will have the click. In your case, this is the document that will do this job. If my element is deep from the root, the element will bubble up through the entire structure to be handle be the document. Ok, it's not a performance concern if you think it's just a click of the mouse but I try to used the syntax with a parent as possible.

Comment: If the event handler will only ever apply to one specific element you might as well attach it directly. Attaching the handler to `document` means that every click anywhere in the document gets tested to see if it was on an element that matches the "#addEvent" selector. A delegated handler is more useful if you need to match multiple elements within a particular container, especially elements that are getting created or updated dynamically such that the handler should only be executed for elements that match its selector at the time the event occurs.

Comment: But in anyways, the delegated handler will always be more performant right? And if it just take a little bit of time for thinking about what is the most specific container of the element that I want to listen, it's not a big deal. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).on("click", $("#addEvent"), addEvent);` should be `$(document).on("click", "#addEvent", addEvent);`, the optional selector for `.on()` is a string, I'm not too sure about the `addEvent`, is that actual code or just pieces?

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/DYXTG/

API: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Rest I hope it helps the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).on("click", "#addEvent", addEvent);


function addEvent() {
    alert("Test");
}
​
```

Comment: You found exactly the same error than @Musa. I can't give you more than a point but thank you very much. Your time is appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
​$(document​).ready(function(){
    $("#addEvent").on("click", event); 
});

function event(){
    alert("Test");
}
```

​
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnPfb/)

or simply:

```
​$(document​).ready(function(){
    $("#addEvent").click(event); 
});

function event(){
    alert("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#addEvent").click(addEvent);
```

Comment: But that doesn't do the same thing as (what was presumably intended to be) a delegated event handler.

Comment: @nnnnn Exactly what I said in comments of my questions but you resume my explaination in 10 times less words :)